# Managing AppRoles using Azure SDK for python, or Microsoft Graph API

Tags: python, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-sdk, azure-sdk-python

I am lost in my searches, and cannot find any specific documentation regarding creating/Deleting,... App Roles.

My aim is to create an App Roles, preferably using python, here is my code

```
import requests
from msal import ConfidentialClientApplication

# Define the Azure AD credentials and API endpoints
tenant_id = "<your tenant ID>"
client_id = "<your client ID>"
client_secret = "<your client secret>"

authority_url = f'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}'
scope = ['https://graph.microsoft.com/.default']

# api_version = 'beta'
api_version = 'v1.0'

# Define the app role properties
app_role_name = 'APIAppRole'
app_role_description = 'app role for API user'

# Authenticate and get an access token using the MSAL library
app = ConfidentialClientApplication(
    client_id=client_id,
    client_credential=client_secret,
    authority=authority_url
)
token = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=scope)

# Create the app role using the Microsoft Graph API
url = f'https://graph.microsoft.com/{api_version}/applications/{client_id}'
headers = {
    'Authorization': f'Bearer {token["access_token"]}',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
body = {
    'allowedMemberTypes': [
        'User',
        'Group'
    ],
    'displayName': app_role_name,
    'description': app_role_description,
    'id': 'lkjasldkjpq9u934l',
    'isEnabled': True,
    'value': app_role_name
}
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=body)
response.raise_for_status()
```

this raises this error:

```
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 405 Client Error: Method Not Allowed for url: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/656
```

what is the correct way to create an AppRoles programmatically?

Comment: try `patch`? reading the docs I'm a little confused if its `post` of `patch`, but either way its probably better\easier to use SDK: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-python

Comment: @4c74356b41 this library is in preview! will have breaking changes, for the `patch` I will get `requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/6xxx`

Comment: this looks like your token is wrong or you dont have permissions

Comment: you mean the API Permissions in Application?

Comment: no, i mean authorization header in your request

Comment: I used the secret_id and I checked if that is wrong I will get another type of error, but after I gave the application permission to the API now I do not get anymore 403 but I got `requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/6`

Comment: you probably need to use application objectid (or appid, i always forget) instead of your service principal ID

Comment: @4c74356b41 right, it has to be the **Object ID**, but still I get the error 404, and I found it is because of the `patch`, as it cannot find any AppRole existed with that name to patch it, so I came back to my first question, **is it possible to create a new App Role programmatically?**

Comment: it definitely should be possible to do that

Comment: it was so confusing this type of errors, but found the issue, the I have to add the **"appRoles "** to my request body, I will add the solution

Answer (score 0):

Some notes which I think it is important to mention them, when you create an application, the appRoles will be created on Manifest as an empty list, that means we do not have to search for **POST** method which was my first issue, as @4c74356b41 mentioned we have to use **PATCH** method to update the application properties ([Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http))

second issue was the request body, and here is the correct one:

```
body = {
    "appRoles": [
        {
            'allowedMemberTypes': [
                'User'
            ],
            'displayName': app_role_name,
            'description': app_role_description,
            'id': str(uuid.uuid4()),
            'isEnabled': "true",
            "origin": "Application",
            'value': app_role_name
        }
    ]
}
```

for permission, it is necessary to add Delegated **Application.ReadWrite.All** in API permission, and for URL use the **Object ID**

```
PATCH /applications/{applicationObjectId}
```

here is the final code,

```
import requests
import uuid
from msal import ConfidentialClientApplication

# Define the Azure AD credentials and API endpoints
tenant_id = "<your tenant ID>"
client_id = "<your client ID>"
client_secret = "<your client secret>"
object_id = "<your application object ID>"

authority_url = f'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}'
scope = ['https://graph.microsoft.com/.default']
api_version = 'v1.0'

# Define the app role properties
app_role_name = 'APIAppRole'
app_role_description = 'app role for API user'

# Authenticate and get an access token using the MSAL library
app = ConfidentialClientApplication(
    client_id=client_id,
    client_credential=client_secret,
    authority=authority_url
)
token = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=scope)

# Create the app role using the Microsoft Graph API
url = f'https://graph.microsoft.com/{api_version}/applications/{object_id}'
headers = {
    'Authorization': f'Bearer {token["access_token"]}',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
body = {
    "appRoles": [
        {
            'allowedMemberTypes': [
                'User'
            ],
            'displayName': app_role_name,
            'description': app_role_description,
            'id': str(uuid.uuid4()),
            'isEnabled': "true",
            "origin": "Application",
            'value': app_role_name
        }
    ]
}
response = requests.patch(url, headers=headers, json=body)
response.raise_for_status()
```

Keep in mind the values for **allowedMemberTypes** are **User** which represents *Users/Groups* and **Application** which represents *Applications* ([appRole resource type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/approle?view=graph-rest-1.0))

another important note is, code tries to delete pre-existed app roles, it fails if they are active but if they are deactivated then it will be deleted, so if you want to avoid them from deletion or failing script then you have to move all the app roles to your code.

Comment: alternatively you can do a `get` and merge approles in code and send `patch`